# How to update based on not existence in another table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

This is the database server I use:

Server type: MariaDB

Server connection: SSL is not being used

Server version: 10.5.8-MariaDB - MariaDB Server

Protocol version: 10

I have a table of Users, one of the values is "isGroupLeader".

Anotther table is Groups, where the Groups have leaders.

One User can be lader of multiple groups.

When I change the leader, I want to check if the old leader is still leader on another group or not.
If he's not a leader in another group, then I'll set his isGroupLeader to false.

Also in pseudocode:

```
if (TheUser.userID is NOT in (groupLeader column of Groups table)) {
   TheUser.isGroupLeader = false;
}
```

How do I do it in MySQL query MariaDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can maintain the state of the `isGroupLeader` column in the `users` table using triggers on `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` into `groups`. On an insert, set the `isGroupLeader` flag of the `groupLeader` to true. On update, you need to set the flag of the new `groupLeader` value, and possibly clear (if they are not group leader of another group) the flag of the old `groupLeader` value. On delete, clear the user's `isGroupLeader` flag if they are no longer a leader of any group. Note that the `UPDATE` and `DELETE` triggers *must* run after the `UPDATE/DELETE` to ensure that the `EXISTS` clause doesn't match the row which is being updated or deleted.

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER addLeader AFTER INSERT ON groups
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE users 
  SET isGroupLeader = true
  WHERE userID = NEW.groupLeader;
END

CREATE TRIGGER updateLeader AFTER UPDATE ON groups
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE users 
  SET isGroupLeader = userID = NEW.groupLeader
                   OR EXISTS (SELECT * FROM groups WHERE groupLeader = OLD.groupLeader)
  WHERE userID IN(OLD.groupLeader, NEW.groupLeader);
END

CREATE TRIGGER deleteLeader AFTER DELETE ON groups
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE users 
  SET isGroupLeader = EXISTS (SELECT * FROM groups WHERE groupLeader = OLD.groupLeader)
  WHERE userID = OLD.groupLeader;
END
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=855fe5e9c5271403445f5b277c536e6f)

Comment: @Coder88 Did this answer your question? If not, could you provide more information to help answer it?

Comment: thank you for your time, but I haven't tested it yet. I think I can figure it out from your answer.

Comment: @Coder88 no worries, I just wanted to see if you needed any more help. You shouldn't accept until you've tested.